# Manually Index an entity's property on datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

On [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com), you can go to edit entity mode in each entity at `Storage -> Cloud Datastore -> Query` and mark the property as 'Indexed' or 'Not Indexed', as shown in the screenshot below.  But doing that is not feasible if there are more than a few entities.

Is there any way to manually index entity's property in bulk?

The only approach that I can think of is to write a temporary script which will read all entities, index the relevant property and write it back to the datastore.

Is there any better approach other than writing such temporary scripts?

*Screenshot:*
[image: Screenshot: Manually index an entity]

**Note :** My project is in Java.

Here is the structure of my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id Long customerId;
    //(...)
    @Index String deviceId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to write the script.

As the Datastore is schemaless and as each Entity can have its own per-property index definition there is no way to do this in bulk other than writing your own tool/script.

Comment: `Datastore is schemaless` explains everything.